# What is the difference between Terraform "Module" and "Child Module"

Tags: terraform, documentation

I was going through the Terraform documentation for `init` and found the following:

> #### Child Module Installation
>
> During init, the configuration is searched for module blocks, and the source code for referenced modules is retrieved from the locations given in their source arguments.
>
> Re-running init with modules already installed will install the sources for any modules that were added to configuration since the last init, but will not change any already-installed modules. Use -upgrade to override this behavior, updating all modules to the latest available source code.
>
> To skip child module installation, use -get=false. Note that some other init steps can complete only when the module tree is complete, so it's recommended to use this flag only when the working directory was already previously initialized with its child modules.

Firstly, let me clarify my understanding of a **Child Module**. **Child Module** are modules that are defined within a **Module**

### Problems

Now I have multiple points of confusion in the above documentation section:

1. In the first paragraph, the documentation talks about the installation of **Modules**. Shouldn't the documentation focus on **Child Modules** instead?
2. Again the second paragraph does the same. Let's assume that the same concept works for both shouldn't that be explicitly specified?
3. In the third paragraph, the sentence speaks about skipping **Child Module** installation but the `terraform init -help` displays the following for `-get=false`.

```bash
# Terraform v1.6.4 on linux_amd64

-get=false              Disable downloading modules for this configuration.
```

### Conclusions

There are only two conclusions that I could come up with:

1. **Module** and **Child Module** are interchangeable terms.
2. There is an issue with how the documentation is written.

Comment: It would probably be more clear if "child module" was replaced with "declared module", and if "module" was clarified to express whether it was all modules, root module, or declared modules.

Comment: I believe "child module" can stay the same as it is part of the Terraform terminology but I definitely agree with your point on clarifying the usage of "module" in the above section. Thank you, this helps me get a bit more clarity.

Comment: The accepted answer and @matthew-schuchard comment together solves my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Module and Child Module are interchangeable terms.

Both are **NOT** the same. The documentation [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules#the-root-module) is very clear.

- **Root module or module ::**

> Every Terraform configuration has at least one module, known as its
> root module, which consists of the resources defined in the .tf files
> in the main working directory.

- **Child Modules ::**

> A Terraform module (usually the root module of a configuration) can
> call other modules to include their resources into the configuration.
> A module that has been called by another module is often referred to
> as a child module. Child modules can be called multiple times within
> the same configuration, and multiple configurations can use the same
> child module.

Below is one of the module examples. It invokes another module `a`. For the module `a`, `root` is referred to as a child module.

```
module "root" {
  source = "./a"
}
```

Below is another example of a `root` module. It doesn't invoke a module but just creates `aws_vpc` resources.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

One can have nested modules as well but to keep it simple just think of only `root` & `child` modules.

Comment: Makes sense but then that means that the documentation mention above in the question is unclear.

Comment: I don't think it's unclear. You are confused between `init` & `modules`. Both aren't same. `init` downloads required modules from configuration & adds it to the workspace. If the sources are already present, it won't redo that. This is applicable in case of upgrade of modules or provider versions. Totally a different topic.